# Не выполняется метод, но и нет сообщения об ошибке

Tags: java

При выполнении базового задания столкнулась с тем, что одна из строчек кода просто не выполняется. При этом не выводится никаких сообщений об ошибке. Выполняла, вроде бы, всё согласно указаниям в книге. Подскажите в чём ошибка?

Класс **Pet**:

```
public class Pet {
int age;
float weight;
float height;
String color;

public void sleep() { 
    System.out.println("Спокойной ночи! До завтра");
}

public void eat () {
    System.out.println("Я очень голоден, давай перекусим!");
    }
public String say (String aWord) {
    String petResponse = "Ну ладно!! " + aWord;
    return petResponse;
}
}
```

Класс **Fish**:

```
public class Fish extends Pet {
int currentDepth=0;
public int dive(int howDeep){
    currentDepth=currentDepth + howDeep;
    System.out.println("Ныряю на глубину "
    + howDeep + " футов");
    System.out.println("Я на глубине "
    + currentDepth + " футов ниже уровня моря");
    return currentDepth;

}
public String say(String something){
return "Ты чё не знаешь, что рыбы не разговаривают?";

}
}
```

Класс **FishMaster**:

```
public class FishMaster extends Pet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fish myFish = new Fish();
        myFish.dive(2);
        myFish.dive(3);
        myFish.sleep();
        myFish.say("Привет");
    }
}
```

При запуске в консоль он выводит следующее:

```
Ныряю на глубину 2 футов
Я на глубине 2 футов ниже уровня моря
Ныряю на глубину 3 футов
Я на глубине 5 футов ниже уровня моря 
Cпокойной ночи! До завтра
```

При этом строка `myFish.say("Привет")` остаётся словно бы проигнорированной.

Comment: Я иногда пишу так, чтобы не запутаться: String s = myFish.say("Привет"); System.out.println(s);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что все остальные команды выводят что-то в консоль `System.out.println("")`, a `myFish.say()` возвращает `String` и никуда ничего не выводит. Вам в методе `main` надо написать `System.out.println(myFish.say("Привет"))`. Тогда метод `say` передаст в `System.out.println` стринговое выражение и тот выведет его в консоль.

Comment: при введении команды `System.out.println(myFish.say"Привет")` выдаёт ошибку: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 say cannot be resolved or is not a field
 Syntax error on token ""Привет"", delete this token".
Если в () заключать "Привет", тогда он просто пишет "Привет", а не выдаёт нужную фразу. 
Что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Извиняюсь, я опечатку допустил  `System.out.println(myFish.say("Привет"))`. "Привет" должно быть в скобках, т.к. это аргумент метода `say()`